# Windows boot directly from Debian (from running system, warm boot)

Tags: linux, windows, boot, debian, root

How can I boot Windows from Debian without actually rebooting?

I mean I want just go directly to the booting process from an already loaded linux from the ring 0 code, when linux core suppose to annihilate, just like I was at the PC startup and had chosen to boot Windows.

Implying I have a root access and I just do not want to waste time waiting for a full-reboot (but I have time to post here and wait for answer)

Also, if I somehow get ring 0 privileges in Windows can I boot back into linux?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Is it possible to reboot a Linux OS without rebooting the hardware?](http://serverfault.com/q/678024/58408), but switching from Linux to Windows rather than just restarting Linux?

Comment: @michael yes, I want to switch, not just restart linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Hot booting from one OS to another OS is not the same thing as booting that second OS from the bootloader. For one, hardware devices will not be in states that the OS may expect at boot time, and will need to know it has to recover from that. In some configurations, the hardware may even prevent it (for example, UEFI's secure boot features).

So while it's theoretically quite feasible, I don't think it's possible right now without a lot of hard work.

Comment: But this system did not have UEFI.

Comment: That was only one example that makes it completely impossible. It doesn't change the fact that the guest OS has to be aware it is hot-rebooted and not booted normally.

Comment: What's about linux from win? It's very customizable.